# Using own handler for Jquery Oembed

Tags: javascript, jquery, oembed

I'm trying to use my own function (never liked `$(document).ready()`) to dynamically load  an embed from an URL.

I'm trying like this:

```
function video(donde,url) {
    $("#"+donde).oembed(url);
    return false;
}
```

And an example of use would be:

```
<div class="texto">
  [my title]
  <span style="float: right;">
      <img onclick="video('video68084','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORZTCQjAuZY');" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/ORZTCQjAuZY/default.jpg" alt="preview" onerror="this.src='images/linket.png';" class="caja_con_sombra" style="width: 80px; height: 60px;">  </span>
  <div style="float: left; width: 76%;">
       [my description]
  </div>
  <div id="video68084"></div>
</div>
```

Which jumps:

```
b.type is not a function
[Interrumpir en este error] b.ready);var j=false;try{j=E.frameElem...ow(j))return false;if(j.constructor&&
```

Onclick vía **firebug** :(

Any idea what I'm missing? The error source file is jquery.min.js :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing anything, you found a bug in the oembed plugin. Nice find, maybe you have a future career in quality assurance :)

Looks like both oembed and jQuery want to use `.type` but jQuery is ending up with oembed's string `.type` where it wants its own function `.type`.

The [oembed plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-oembed/) works fine with jQuery-1.3.2 but breaks as of jQuery-1.4.3.

You can pull a functional version of the oembed plugin from this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZVhUn/1/

This problem has been [reported several times](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-oembed/issues/list) but the oembed author doesn't seem to be listening. Here's a fixed version of the plugin if you want it:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.oembed = function(url, options, callback) {

        options = $.extend(true, $.fn.oembed.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var container = $(this),
                resourceURL = (url != null) ? url : container.attr("href"),
                provider;

            if (!callback) callback = function(container, oembed) {            
                 $.fn.oembed.insertCode(container, options.embedMethod, oembed);
            };

            if (resourceURL != null) {
                provider = getOEmbedProvider(resourceURL);

                if (provider != null) {                        
                    provider.params = getNormalizedParams(options[provider.name]) || {};
                    provider.maxWidth = options.maxWidth;
                    provider.maxHeight = options.maxHeight;                                        
                    provider.embedCode(container, resourceURL, callback);
                    return;
                }
            }

            callback(container, null);
        });
    };

    // Plugin defaults
    $.fn.oembed.defaults = {
        maxWidth: null,
        maxHeight: null,
        embedMethod: "replace" // "auto", "append", "fill"
    };

    $.fn.oembed.insertCode = function(container, embedMethod, oembed) {
        if (oembed == null)
            return;
        switch(embedMethod)
        {
            case "auto":                
                if (container.attr("href") != null) {
                    $.fn.oembed.insertCode(container, "append", oembed);
                }
                else {
                    $.fn.oembed.insertCode(container, "replace", oembed);
                };
                break;
            case "replace":    
                container.replaceWith(oembed.code);
                break;
            case "fill":
                container.html(oembed.code);
                break;
            case "append":
                var oembedContainer = container.next();
                if (oembedContainer == null || !oembedContainer.hasClass("oembed-container")) {
                    oembedContainer = container
                        .after('<div class="oembed-container"></div>')
                        .next(".oembed-container");
                    if (oembed != null && oembed.provider_name != null)
                        oembedContainer.toggleClass("oembed-container-" + oembed.provider_name);        
                }
                oembedContainer.html(oembed.code);                
                break;            
        }
    };

    $.fn.oembed.getPhotoCode = function(url, data) {
        var alt = data.title ? data.title : '';
        alt += data.author_name ? ' - ' + data.author_name : '';
        alt += data.provider_name ? ' - ' +data.provider_name : '';
        var code = '<div><a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + data.url + '" alt="' + alt + '"/></a></div>';
        if (data.html)
            code += "<div>" + data.html + "</div>";
        return code;
    };

    $.fn.oembed.getVideoCode = function(url, data) {
        var code = data.html;
        return code;
    };

    $.fn.oembed.getRichCode = function(url, data) {
        var code = data.html;
        return code;
    };

    $.fn.oembed.getGenericCode = function(url, data) {
        var title = (data.title != null) ? data.title : url,
            code = '<a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a>';
        if (data.html)
            code += "<div>" + data.html + "</div>";
        return code;
    };

    $.fn.oembed.isAvailable = function(url) {
        var provider = getOEmbedProvider(url);
        return (provider != null);
    };

    /* Private Methods */
    function getOEmbedProvider(url) {
        for (var i = 0; i < providers.length; i++) {
            if (providers[i].matches(url))
                return providers[i];
        }
        return null;
    }

    function getNormalizedParams(params) {
        if (params == null)
            return null;
        var normalizedParams = {};
        for (var key in params) {
            if (key != null)
                normalizedParams[key.toLowerCase()] = params[key];
        }
        return normalizedParams;
    }

    var providers = [
        new OEmbedProvider("fivemin", "5min.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("amazon", "amazon.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("flickr", "flickr", "http://flickr.com/services/oembed", "jsoncallback"),    
        new OEmbedProvider("googlevideo", "video.google."),
        new OEmbedProvider("hulu", "hulu.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("imdb", "imdb.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("metacafe", "metacafe.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("qik", "qik.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("revision3", "revision3.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("slideshare", "slideshare.net"),
        new OEmbedProvider("twitpic", "twitpic.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("viddler", "viddler.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("vimeo", "vimeo.com", "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json"),
        new OEmbedProvider("wikipedia", "wikipedia.org"),
        new OEmbedProvider("wordpress", "wordpress.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("youtube", "youtube.com"),
        new OEmbedProvider("vids.myspace.com", "vids.myspace.com", "http://vids.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=oembed"),
        new OEmbedProvider("screenr", "screenr.com", "http://screenr.com/api/oembed.json")
    ];

    function OEmbedProvider(name, urlPattern, oEmbedUrl, callbackparameter) {
        this.name = name;
        this.urlPattern = urlPattern;
        this.oEmbedUrl = (oEmbedUrl != null) ? oEmbedUrl : "http://oohembed.com/oohembed/";
        this.callbackparameter = (callbackparameter != null) ? callbackparameter : "callback";
        this.maxWidth = 500;
        this.maxHeight = 400;

        this.matches = function(externalUrl) {
            // TODO: Convert to Regex
            return externalUrl.indexOf(this.urlPattern) >= 0;
        };

        this.getRequestUrl = function(externalUrl) {

            var url = this.oEmbedUrl;

            if (url.indexOf("?") <= 0)
                url = url + "?";
            else
                url = url + "&";

            var qs = "";

            if (this.maxWidth != null && this.params["maxwidth"] == null)
                this.params["maxwidth"] = this.maxWidth;                

            if (this.maxHeight != null && this.params["maxheight"] == null)
                this.params["maxheight"] = this.maxHeight;

            for (var i in this.params) {
                // We don't want them to jack everything up by changing the callback parameter
                if (i == this.callbackparameter)
                  continue;

                // allows the options to be set to null, don't send null values to the server as parameters
                if (this.params[i] != null)
                    qs += "&" + escape(i) + "=" + this.params[i];
            }            


            url += "format=json&url=" + escape(externalUrl) +             
                    qs + 
                    "&" + this.callbackparameter + "=?";

            return url;
        };

        this.embedCode = function(container, externalUrl, callback) {

            var request = this.getRequestUrl(externalUrl);

            $.getJSON(request, function(data) {

                var code, type = data.type;
                var oembed = $.extend({ }, data);

                switch (type) {
                    case "photo":
                        oembed.code = $.fn.oembed.getPhotoCode(externalUrl, data);
                        break;
                    case "video":
                        oembed.code = $.fn.oembed.getVideoCode(externalUrl, data);
                        break;
                    case "rich":
                        oembed.code = $.fn.oembed.getRichCode(externalUrl, data);
                        break;
                    default:
                        oembed.code = $.fn.oembed.getGenericCode(externalUrl, data);
                        break;
                }

                callback(container, oembed);
            });
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The only change is that I replaced `var oembed = $.extend(data);` with `var oembed = $.extend({ }, data);` in `this.embedCode` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: is better if you do it because i have to admit that i haven't understood very well, so, in my case, your code is my solution?  i don't get it either Thank you!

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet: The oembed plugin has problems with recent versions of jQuery, a small change to the oembed source fixes the problem. If you go to the jsfiddle.net link, a fixed version of the oembed plugin is in the JavaScript panel, you can use that instead of the oembed plugin that you downloaded. I'll send a patch in.

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet: This problem has been found by a few other people (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-oembed/issues/list) but the oembed author doesn't seem to be listening. I updated my jsfiddle with a better fix I'll throw the whole thing in my answer.

Comment: Updated: It works fine on chrome and safari, can't get it work on firefox though. Why could be possible? (if want to try: http://keepyourlinks.com/ any image with the play icon (but not the icon, the image :P))

Comment: Seems to be working okay for me in both Firefox and Chrome. Does the jsfiddle link work for you in Firefox?

Comment: Do you have an old version of the oembed plugin stuck in your Firefox cache? Does Firebug have anything to say?

Comment: wel it jumps same error I posted on the first question, but infinite tiemes. Just to make sure, it worked to you on my website or only on jsfiddle you sent me? thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I tried both the jsfiddle and keepyourlinks.com in both Firefox and Chrome. Try clearing your Firefox cache and trying again, sounds like you have the old `/js/jquery.oembed.min.js` in your cache; you can also try renaming `jquery.oembed.min.js` to `jquery.oembed.js` (on both your web server and in the site's HTML) just to be sure.